# WCF CollectionDataContract not using ItemName

Tags: wcf

I have a locally hosted WCF service where I try to use WCF's CollectionDataContract.

The Service-contract looks like this:

```
[OperationContract]
GetSalesDeliveryNotesResponse GetSalesDeliveryNotes(GetSalesDeliveryNotesRequest request);
```

The GetSalesDeliveryNotesResponse-class has a property Serials which looks like this:

```
[DataMember]
public SerialList Serials { get; set; }
```

The SerialList class is an inner class of the GetSalesDeliveryNotesResponse and looks like this:

```
[CollectionDataContract(ItemName = "Serial")]
public class SerialList : List<string> {
    public SerialList() : base() { }

    public SerialList(List<string> l) : base() {
        AddRange(l);
    }
}
```

The code I use to set this property looks like this:

```
Serials = new GetSalesDeliveryNotesResponse.DeliveryNote.Order.Orderline.SerialList(
    (from s in r.Descendants("Serial") 
    select s.Value).ToList()
)
```

where r is a collection of XElements (the service connects to an Oracle database, executes a stored procedure which returns an XML which my service has to serialize to the client).

Note that the DeliveryNote, Order and Orderline are also inner classes of the Response-object, but are omitted for brevity (as are a couple of other properties).

The issue I'm having is that the Serials-object in my response (client-side) looks like this:

```
<Serials>
    <string>123789456</string>
</Serials>
```

when I would expect it to look like this:

```
<Serials>
    <Serial>123789456</Serial>
</Serials>
```

What am I missing here?

//edit:
Some more info:
The client-side implementation of the service has this for the SerialList class:

```
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Runtime.Serialization", "4.0.0.0")]
[System.Runtime.Serialization.CollectionDataContractAttribute(Name="GetSalesDeliveryNotesResponse.DeliveryNote.Order.Orderline.SerialList", Namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/<my_namespace>/DeliveryNoteService.Contract.Response", ItemName="Serial")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
public class SerialList : System.Collections.Generic.List<string> { }
```

Comment: are you sure something is not wrong in your side ? because I have test this code and I have the right xml output. Try with WCFTestClient.

Comment: @cybermaxs: Well now I just feel stupid... the WCFTestClient gives the correct response. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

Apparently my service was correct. Using the WCFTestClient gave the correct response. There was thus a problem with my own testing code.